# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk Keeps asking for credentials when running any command

Tags: python, macos, amazon-web-services, file-permissions, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have the following setup:

- Mac OS X 10.10
- Python 2.7

I did the following steps

1. AWS EB Console Tools added to my path in ~/.bash_profile

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:~/amazon-eb/eb/linux/python2.7/
   export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx
   export AWS_SECRET_KEY=xxx
   export AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE=~/.aws/credentials
   ```
2. AWS Credentials in `~/.aws/credentials`

   ```
   [default]
   AWSAccessKeyId=xxx
   AWSSecretKey=xxx
   ```
3. Created a project with `.elasticbeanstalk/config` file

   ```
   [global]
   ApplicationName=Oselot Wordpress Blog
   DevToolsEndpoint=git.elasticbeanstalk.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
   EnvironmentName=oselotWordpressBlog-env
   Region=us-east-1
   ```
4. When I try to run `eb status` it asks me for my credentials

   ```
   Anatoliys-MBP:oselot-blog toli$ eb status
   To get your AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key, 
     visit "https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials".
   Enter your AWS Access Key ID:
   ```

It works fine when I enter my credentials but it's very annoying to have to do it every time. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I guess correct name of the env variable is `AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE` instead of `AWS_CREDENTIALS_PATH`, as in [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/usingCLI.html)

Comment: Changed. Still no dice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran `eb init` and it created the credentials file in the correct place

Turns out the correct place to put the credentials file is:

```
~/.elasticbeanstalk/aws_credential_file
```

You simply put

```
AWSAccessKeyId=xxx
AWSSecretKey=xxx
```

and it works. Who knew...

Comment: I examined the code of eb script, and `~/.elasticbeanstalk/aws_credential_file` is a default config location overriden by `AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE` setting. Glad that this works, but still am sure you misspelled smething, or haven't restarted shell, or env wasn't set correctly for some reason.

Comment: Hmm...yeah I will do more experimenting later on. For now though...I works :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to grant reading permissions on  aws_credential_file
When i ran $ eb push => I got the following error message
  NOTE: The "git aws.push" command uses the AWS credentials that are in 
  the following file:
  /Users/MOH/.elasticbeanstalk/aws_credential_file

This AWS credentials file is not readable. Grant read permissions to 
  the file or edit the ".elasticbeanstalk/config" configuration file to 
  reference a different file. The credentials file must use the following 
  format:

so i went to ~/.elasticbeanstalk/
then typed $sudo chmod 644 aws_credential_file 
and problem resolved.